# Is there an easier way to implement Point Cloud Library?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu-14.04, windows-7-x64, point-cloud-library

I've been assigned a task to use PCL (Point Cloud Library) for computer vision. I just recently got an Xbox 360 Kinect so I can plug it in to my computer.

The website has an "all-in-one" installer, but even though they make it seem like it's easy to implement, it really isn't. I've tried both Windows and Linux. If I can get it working on either OS I would be satisfied.

I've looked through countless forums about this and none of them have solved my issues. Let me state the issues for you below so you can understand what I'm dealing with.

When I type `lsusb` it shows that I have the Xbox camera and audio connected, but not the Xbox motor.

When I launch the one program that I do have installed- `pcl_openni_viewer` it pops open two windows; both of them are nothing but black but I can see that my Kinect is working because it starts using the laser on the left-most camera. After I close out of these windows my ubuntu virtual machine freezes and I have to turn the power off and risk losing data and work that I've done.

These are the commands you can find at http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html which is supposed to make it easy to install PCL.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
```

Seems simple enough right? Not so much. Here's where you can find the Windows all-in-one installer- http://pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html

I've tried to install it multiple times for both 32-bit and 64-bit with both versions; neither of them worked. Here's the error I get when I try to launch Skeletal Viewer (which has nothing to do with PCL)- `NuiInitialize Failed`.

When I try to use NiViewer64 it says this- `The procedure entry point xnOSSeekFile64 could not be located in the dynamic link library OpenNI64.dll.` followed by `The procedure entry point _xnDumpFileClose could not be located in the dynamic link library OpenNI64.dll.`.

Is there anything that I can do to speed this process up? I've been working on this all week and haven't made any progress. Any help is appreciated.

NB: I know Python and R very well, so if those skills will help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux follow these instructions to install the Kinect with PCL:
http://www.pcl-users.org/Can-t-use-Kinect-in-Ubuntu14-04-td4033666.html#a4035318

I've never worked with the Kinect in a virtual machine, please try with a real Ubuntu install before trying in a virtual machine.

For Windows I would not use the PCL all in one, it's outdated. If possible build PCL trunk:
http://www.pcl-users.org/How-to-Guide-Building-PCL-Kinect-amp-Openni-2-for-MSVC2013-amp-Win8-td4038916.html#a4039908